My C code is able to iterate once through and come up with the correct mileage but on the second iteration it fails
The problems objective is to write a program that takes a number of data sets the user would like to enter and then within the data sets it counts how many miles you traveled. For example for the first sample input 20 mph for the first 2 hours, 30 for 2nd - 6th hour and 10 for the seventh hour. The input sequence is the n number of data sets and the the s (speed/mph) and t(time). -1 ends the sequence
Sample Input

3
20 2
30 6
10 7
2
60 1
30 5
4
15 1
25 2
30 3
10 5
-1

Sample output

170 miles
180 miles
90 miles

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n, s, t, timeDiff, newTime, sum, arrSum; //variables
    int arr[100]; //array
    int count = 0; //counter, which i haven't used yet but have been in the habit of doing

    while (n != -1){
        
        scanf("%d", &n);    //Number of data sets to be entered
    
        for(int i=0; i<n ;i++){
            
            timeDiff = t;     //saves last time value
            scanf("%d %d", &s, &t);
            newTime = t - timeDiff;  //subtracts last time value from the new
            
            if (timeDiff == 0){
                sum = s * t;  
                arr[i] = sum;  
            }
            else{
                sum = s * newTime;
                arr[i] = sum;}
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arrSum = arrSum + arr[i];
        }
        printf("You went %d miles \n", arrSum);
      
        sum = 0;
        timeDiff = 0;
        arrSum = 0;
        newTime = 0;
      
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
        count++; 
    }

    return 0;
}

When I initially spotted the probelm I though it was because my array was filled so I had to empty it hence the for loop at the end (tbh im not even sure that's entirely correct). I'm a relatively new programmer to c and have been trying to adjust, but it's proved difficult to say the least.

while (n != -1) -- you never initialized n before this.

You have arrSum = arrSum + arr[i]; but the local variable int arrsum was not initialised.

Hint: initialise variables just before you use them, not after. Those 'zeroing' lines just near the end of main() are in the wrong place.

You need to break out of the loop immediately if -1 is entered as the number of datasets. Your code will continue with the rest of the loop body, even though there's no more input to read.

Your compiler should warn about using uninitialized variables. If not, turn warnings up.

You'll also want to check that scanf succeeded.

In short, as others have pointed out, you have a ton of uninitialized and/or misused variables.
It looks like you're giving it a try, so I'm less concerned about doing your homework for you.
That said, note how I 1) ensure variables have a usable value before using them; and 2) bail out if I don't get suitable input via scanf.
A couple of things to note about your code:

Keep variables at the innermost scope that you can. This not only helps the compiler to optimize the machine code, it also helps the compiler flag errors and warnings.
Depending on C version, you may need to declare variables at wider scopes than where they're used (not actually very relevant unless you're using a very old compiler or taking a course in K&R C). Still, don't initialize them before you need to, but DO initialize them IF you need to.
Use descriptive variable names! n, s, and t are too easy to get confused. Trust me, the time you spend giving them intuitive names will be saved many times over when you're trying to fix your code.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int totalMiles = 0;
    int totalHours = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int nrecs;
    while (scanf("%d", &nrecs) == 1)
    {
        int hours, miles;
        if (nrecs < 0)
            break;
        ++count;
        hours = miles = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < nrecs; ++index)
        {
            int speed, duration;
            if (scanf("%d %d", &speed, &duration) != 2)
            {
                // bad input, report an error and exit
                fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            miles += (speed * duration);
            hours += duration;
        }
        totalMiles += miles;
        totalHours += hours;
    }
    printf("You went %d miles in %d hours\n", totalMiles, totalHours);
    printf("%d blocks processed\n", count);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


What are you referring to in point 2? Do you mean declaring variables in the for() header?

No, though that could be the case if you use a really ancient compiler ;) I was referring instead to the forward declarations of hours and miles, whose declarations could wait until initialization with any relatively modern compiler.

Why not just int hours = 0, miles = 0;? There's no real need to delay the initializations until after the if.

If (nrecs < 0) is true and the compiler isn't smart enough to delay the initialization, you've executed instructions to store values that will never be used. In the overall scheme of things, it's inconsequential, but it's still wasted machine instructions and I try to avoid those.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Writing clean code does not qualify as premature optimization! In fact, if you make a habit of writing clean code in the first place, you may be surprised at how rarely you have to go back and optimize.

I don't see what's unclean about initializing the variables when you declare them. The only reason you're delaying the initialization is because a an inconsequential performance impact, which I consider premature optimization.

There's no need to define either hours or miles before the if statement.  They could be defined and initialized after it: int hours = 0; and int miles = 0;.  That minimizes their scope.  It's only a problem if you are stuck with C90 — and the [tag:c] tag wiki explicitly says "This tag should be used with general questions concerning the C language, as defined in the ISO 9899 standard (the latest version, 9899:2018, unless otherwise specified …)", so assuming at least C99 is not a big assumption.  Yes, I do recognize that there seem to be schools that still use Turbo C on DOS/Windows.

You could circumvent the whole issue by replacing while (scanf("%d", &nrecs) == 1)  { int hours, miles; if (nrecs < 0) break; ++count; hours = miles = 0; for (…) with while (scanf("%d", &nrecs) == 1 && nrecs > 0) { int hours = 0; int miles = 0; count++; for (…).  This works cleanly in C90 as well as later versions of the standard (but the for (int i = 0; …; …) notation requires C99, of course).
